# Unable to connect to oozie server (error code: 500)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, oozie

I was trying to run an oozie workflow using Java API. But while submitting the job, it is giving me an error code 500. Please see the stack trace below.

```
Exception in thread "main" HTTP error code: 500 : Internal Server Error
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.handleError(OozieClient.java:445)
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$JobSubmit.call(OozieClient.java:523)
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$JobSubmit.call(OozieClient.java:493)
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$ClientCallable.call(OozieClient.java:416)
at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.run(OozieClient.java:587)
```

The code I have used is:

```
OozieClient wc = new OozieClient("http://localhost:11000/oozie");
Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();
conf.setProperty("jobTracker", "http://localhost:8021/");
conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH, "localhost:9023/user/688697/jarloc");
// submit and start the workflow job
String jobId = wc.run(conf);
```

The hadoop ecosystem I have used are:
Cloudera Distribution for Hadoop v4.1.2

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: This is one of the annoying problems with OOZIE - you'll need to go check the oozie logs for the actual cause - feel free to repost attaching the error message from oozie.log (under /var/log/oozie maybe?)

Comment: The 500 error is misleading because you think there is a problem with the API or that Oozie went down. It may make sense to make Chris White's reply its own answer. I was able to use this to solve my problem. I forgot to set a -D option that the properties file was expecting. The log had an error there.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is expecting Oozie server to be on the same machine in which you are executing this code, which I believe might be an issue here. Either ensure that you are running the above code on same machine which has oozie server or else replace *'localhost'* with the actual location(full machine name) of the oozie server.